# How to show text input alongside tree nodes in ext js 4

Tags: treeview, extjs4

I was able to create a tree view [using EXTJS 4 ] with context menu[options are add,edit,delete],

So if i right click on any of tree node context menu will appear,

If i click "Edit", a text box should appear at the selected tree node and able to rename it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`Ext.Editor`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Editor) (check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/4Vvjz/)):

```js
var editor = new Ext.Editor({
    field: {
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }
});
tree.menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
  items: [
    // ...
    {text: 'Edit', action: 'edit'},
    // ...
  ]
});
tree.on('itemcontextmenu', function(view, record, HTMLTarget, i, e) {
  // Let's save record and HTMLTarget for further use
  tree.menu.record = record;
  tree.menu.HTMLTarget = HTMLTarget;

  tree.menu.showAt(e.getXY());
  e.preventDefault();
});
tree.menu.on('click', function(menu, item, e){
  if (!item) return;
  switch(item.action) {
    // ...
    case 'edit':
      editor.startEdit(Ext.get(menu.HTMLTarget), menu.record.get('text'));
      editor.on('complete', function(me, value) {
        this.record.set('text', value);
      }, menu, {single: true});
    break;
    // ...
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Molecule Man, thats what exactly im looking. now i will change code as per your suggestion.Thanks again :)

Comment: @Srinivas, give the man an up vote! (it is a great response, yes?)

Answer (score 1):

check this http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?2430-TreePanel-with-Context-Menu

```
function onItemClick(item){
        console.info('You clicked: '+ item.text);
    }
```

...

```
var menuC = new Ext.menu.Menu({ id: 'mainContext', items: [
            { text: 'edit', handler: onItemClick } , { text: 'delete', handler: onItemClick }
            ]
});
```

it's for adding actions for menu items

Comment: hi,thanks fr the reply.I have created context menu already. what i want is to implement the functionality of add,edit,delete the tree nodes on click of context menu options[add,delete..].

Comment: and console.info('You clicked: '+ item.text); there is no use of this as we already in handler function.